# Visual Studio Code: How to Disable `editor.codeActionsOnSave`

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, configuration-files

I find that the `editor.codeActionsOnSave` configuration very annoying because a lot of times when I save, it eats up some time getting some code actions for the language I'm currently using (Golang, for example).

I have no desire nor need for such a feature as I have configured my desired actions upon save elsewhere.

I have already added the following entries on my VS Code configuration file:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {},
"[go]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {}
},
```

However, setting an empty value does not seem to disable this annoying feature because I still get popups that VS Code is getting some code actions.

Previously, `editor.codeActionsOnSave` was set to `null` by default, but this also does not disable the feature.

How do I disable this feature?

***EDIT:*** I also filed a GitHub issue about this [***here.***](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107159)

Comment: It is only set to `null` by default if you clicked "edit in settings.json" but then did nothing when the editor was shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get rid of it by setting it only for go :

```
"[go]": {
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll": true,
      "source.organizeImports": true
  }
}
```

Setting it to null does not work, somehow Go expects it to be set up, and setting it to false globally can be a pain on other projets (I am looking at you react-native project with eslint set up)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try! Although since I'm not working in Go at the moment, it could take a while before I can observe whether it works on my side and accept it as the answer. Many thanks for answering!

Comment: this worked for me! and it's a better answer than the other one that has more votes, because the "[go]": {}   block is essential!

Answer (score 3):

You can delete it or set it to false

```
...
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": false,
    "source.organizeImports": false
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": false
...
```

Comment: Hmm, this looks very promising! I'll try it out and accept this as the answer if it works after observing it for a while. But is `"editor.formatOnSave": false` really mandatory? I find that format on save is very useful.

Comment: UPDATE: Sadly, this didn't work for me. :( I have no idea what code action VS Code is even doing for Golang because I don't have any specified. Many thanks for trying, though! :)

Comment: None of these are mandatory. As said you can even delete them completely.
Sorry it didn't work for you :(